# How do I use multiple REGEXP_REPLACE uses in one formula?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a product sku coming into Data Studio from Google Analytics and I'm wanting to break it into dimension segments as it contains important information.

Here's a couple of example skus:

```
S00GX80-SU39-white-red cardinal-40

S00EN20-S903-yellow mustard-38

NOS-S000010-SF43-Navy-FWhit-39
```

The key information here is the colour and the size, coming towards the end of the SKU.

So far I've used this code to create a new dimension ('NEW SKU') to ensure all skus begin the same:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Product SKU,'NOS-','')
```

And then used the new dimension to create two new dimensions using the following formulas:

Colour - `REGEXP_EXTRACT(New Product Sku, '^(?:[^-]*[-]){2}([^-]*)')`

Size - `REGEXP_EXTRACT(New Product Sku, '^(?:[^-]*[-]){3}([^-]*)')`

These work to a certain extent except when there are extra dashes `-` in the sku. For instance using the SKU's from my original examples only the Yellow Mustard size 38 works correctly.

What I'm looking for is a formula that would take the colour out and a formula that takes the size out. The examples given would then look as follows:

Colour | Size

white-red cardinal | 40

yellow mustard | 38

Navy-FWhit | 39

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is size always the last element of the SKU, and is it always numeric? Does color always come immediately before size? Are colors always only alpha characters, and do the prefixes before them always end in a number? If you can update the question with that additional information, I'm sure we can help you get a working expression

Comment: They're always structured as per the examples. SKU followed by colour followed by size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values on the left and right sides are known, we can simply anchor based on those (also simplified to save you removing the NOS prefix by making it optional):

```
/* SKU */
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product SKU,'(?i)^((?:NOS-)?[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+)')

/* Color */
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product SKU,'(?i)^(?:(?:NOS-)?[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+)-(.+)-(?:[0-9]+)$')

/* Size */
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product SKU,'([0-9]+)$')
```

Note that the `$` assertion anchors to the end of the string just as `^` anchors to the beginning.

I would also add that using the Explore feature from the data source you can list the original SKU and the new calculated fields in a table grid, which makes it easy to identify any corner cases that need to be handled (e.g. filtering to where any of those calculated fields are blank to see what went wrong).

---

**UPDATE:** Here's what I get when running an explore against your examples (file upload source)
[image: Example Google Data Studio "Explore" results grid based on original example SKUs and calculated fields]